# c# value not being stored into accessor

Tags: c#, accessor

I have 4 class files Driver class (contains main method)
UserInput class (contains GenerateLines  & TxtLoadFile methods)
FileHandling.class(contains LoadFile & LoadingFile methods)
Crypting class (empty class at the moment)

My issue is I am trying to get the user to choose which directory out of three to choose a file from. Once chosen I want them to input the file name (.txt) and when that is done I want that value stored and taken to FileHandling class and the LoadFile accessor stores the value into 'TxtFile' variable. I then want to use 'TxtFile' in the method LoadingFile to load the file.
Issue is the value gets stored while in UserInput class but when I call: LoadingFile method in the Driver class it drops the value.

Bear in mind I am student still learning C#, so may not be the best constructed programs as I am just practicing for assignment.

EDIT: I forgot to mention I did check this through debugger but I could not work out how to fix it

Driver class :

```
namespace UniAssignVigereneCipher
{
    class Driver
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserInput UI = new UserInput();
            Crypting CR = new Crypting();
            FileHandling FH = new FileHandling();

            Console.WriteLine(UI.test);
            Console.WriteLine(UI.test2);
            FH.LoadingFile();

        }
    }
}
```

UserInput class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace UniAssignVigereneCipher
{
    class UserInput
    {
        public string test = GenerateLines();
        public string test2 = TxtLoadFile();

        public static string GenerateLines()
        {
            string input;
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to encrypt/decrypt a .txt(t) file  or a piece text string(s)?\r\nPlease type (t) or (s)");
            input = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (input)
            {
                case "t":
                case "T":
                    Console.WriteLine("You have selected a txt file.");
                    break;
                case "s":
                case "S":
                    Console.WriteLine("You have selected to input your own text string.");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            return input;

        }
        public static string TxtLoadFile()
        {
            FileHandling Location = new FileHandling();
            int n;
            string FileInput;
            string TxtFileLoc;
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose the location of the .txt file you would like to load from.\r\n1 (Current Location): {0} \r\n2 (Desktop): {1} \r\n3 (My Documents): {2}",  Location.CurrentDir, Location.DesktopPath,Location.DocumentsPath);
            FileInput = Console.ReadLine();
            bool test = int.TryParse(FileInput, out n);

            switch (n)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("File Location: {0} \r\nName of file to load: ", Location.CurrentDir);
                    TxtFileLoc = Console.ReadLine();
                    Location.LoadFile = Location.DesktopPath + "\\" + TxtFileLoc;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("File Location: {0} \r\nName of file to load: ", Location.DesktopPath);
                    TxtFileLoc = Console.ReadLine();
                    Location.LoadFile = Location.DesktopPath + "\\" + TxtFileLoc;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("File Location: {0} \r\nPName of file to load: ", Location.DocumentsPath);
                    TxtFileLoc = Console.ReadLine();
                    Location.LoadFile = Location.DocumentsPath + "\\" + TxtFileLoc;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }         
            return FileInput;
        }
    }
}
```

FileHandling class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace UniAssignVigereneCipher
{
    class FileHandling
    {
        public string DesktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
        public string DocumentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        public string CurrentDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;



        string TxtFile;

        public string LoadFile
        {
            get
            {
                return TxtFile;
            }
            set
            {
                TxtFile = value;
            }
        }

        public void LoadingFile()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("name:" + TxtFile);
            StreamReader LF = new StreamReader(TxtFile);
            string FileContent = LF.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(FileContent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `LoadingFile()` method uses `FileHandling.TxtFile`, but your user input is in `UserInput`.

Comment: @mac10688 well I made a thread a while back people saying I didn't post enough code xD and now I posted it all and it's not good enough! can't win on this site drives me nuts. Let me explain in more detail in the UserInput class when they enter the file name I want it `Location.LoadFile = Location.DesktopPath + "\\" + TxtFileLoc;` to store the path and the file name entered but when LoadingFile() gets executed the value is not stored anymore in Location.LoadFile

Comment: Sorry about that. But I think recursive nailed your problem.

Comment: @recursive ah okay so I need to reconfigure it and put the user input in `Driver.cs` ? Or do I call the method while in `UserInput`?

Comment: @JakeGroves it's not clear from the tour (which I assume you've read). You need *just enough code to showcase your problem*. Try to remove anything that's not directly related. (This means you have to do more leg-work to isolate the problem.)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserInput UI = new UserInput();
        Crypting CR = new Crypting();
        FileHandling FH = new FileHandling();

        Console.WriteLine(UI.test);
        Console.WriteLine(UI.test2);
        FH.LoadFile = UI.test2;
        FH.LoadingFile();
    }
```

Note: It's very odd to put your worker methods into the class construction.  it would probably be better to call them like this:

```
        UserInput UI = new UserInput();
        string textFile = UI.TxtLoadFile();
        //... later on...
        FH.LoadFile = textFile;
```

Comment: thanks for that reply I see what you mean and it did a partial fix, it is not recognising the file name entered now though and just a few errors TextFile is supposed to be TxtFile (note incase people see later) that's all and also when I choose it to be Desktop location it is persistent on being current directory location.

Comment: @JakeGroves Since you're working with two classes, you need to take responsibility to move data from one class to the other.